# How to stop a bezier spline from going beyond the coordinate axes?

Tags: algorithm, bezier, uibezierpath

In my iOS app I draw a bezier spline through a set of 2D points using an algorithm that calculates set of first and second control points for each bezier curve joining two consecutive points.
The algorithm works brilliantly but the my problem is that now I am displaying this curve on a graph with X and Y axes.

Whenever there are couple of points or  on the axes,  and rest of them inside, the curve seems to take a U-turn and go beyond the axis and come back in two go through both the points and the ones that are inside.

From the algorithm perspective there is nothing wrong n that. Controls point in such case will be generated out side the coordinate axes.

Is there a way that I can go through the points and see if some of them are on the axes and modify the controls points such that the curve instead of going outside the curve just passes through both points on the axis as a straight line coinciding with coordinate axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Detecting a curve that goes off-screen

Bezier curves are actually just polynomial equations.  There are [multiple types of Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Examination_of_cases), corresponding to the differing degrees of the curve.

So, just take the equations that are generated *(one for `x`, one for `y`)*, and find the roots *(points where they pass through 0)*.  If the roots exist, the curve passes the axis.

For example, for a quadratic (degree=2) Bezier curve, given our three points (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>), (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) the [equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) are

```
x(t) = (x0 - 2x1 + x2)t2 - 2(x0 + x1)t + x0
y(t) = (y0 - 2y1 + y2)t2 - 2(y0 + y1)t + y0
0 <= t <= 1
```

---

At this point, we could use the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula) to solve for `t`, and check that the solution either doesn't exist or is outside our domain of `[0,1]` for `t`.  However, there is another method that generalizes for cubic Bezier curves, without having to touch the complicated [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_formula#General_formula_of_roots) - just check the extrema-points.  These are the points where the derivative = 0.  Since the derivative is

```
x'(t) = 2(x0 - 2x1 + x2)t - 2(x0 + x1)
y'(t) = 2(y0 - 2y1 + y2)t - 2(y0 + y1)
```

This means the extrema are at

```
textrema-x = (x0 + x1) / (x0 - 2x1 + x2)
textrema-y = (y0 + y1) / (y0 - 2y1 + y2)
```

Thus, just check that x(t<sub>extrema-x</sub>) > 0 and y(t<sub>extrema-y</sub>) > 0  *(We are assuming the endpoints x<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are known to be on the screen aka > 0)*.  For cubic Bezier curves, do the same thing, but use the quadratic-formula to solve for the extremas *(there are two extremas for each of `x` and `y` in that case)*.

---

### Preventing the curve from going off-screen

If we solve for x(t<sub>extrema-x</sub>) > 0 by taking our equation above for t<sub>extrema-x</sub> and plugging it into x(t), we find after a bit of algebra that, to prevent crossing the x-axis, we need

```
-4x0x1 + x0x2 - x12 > 0 if (x0 + x2) > 2x1
-4x0x1 + x0x2 - x12 < 0 if (x0 + x2) < 2x1
```

*(if (x<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>) = 2x<sub>1</sub>, we are moving linearly from x<sub>0</sub> to x<sub>2</sub> so, assuming both are positive, we **can't** cross the x-axis)*

A bit of staring at these equations should convince you that if (x<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>) > 2x<sub>1</sub>, we can simply decrease x<sub>1</sub> until the lefthand condition is met; and if (x<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>) < 2x<sub>1</sub>, we can simply increase x<sub>1</sub> until the condition is met.  The equations for `y` are analogous.

---

This tells us how to prevent the curve from going off the left *(`x=0`)* and top *(`y=0`)* portions of the screen - what about the right *(`x=screen_width`)* and bottom *(`y=screen_height`)*?

We can do this easily by imagining we are flipping the screen to its mirror-image, so that the right-side is `x=0` and the left-side is `x=screen_width`.  This can be done by replacing every instance of `x` with `(screen_width-x)` in all equations above, and checking our conditions.  Then, for example, when before in the first case we'd decrease x<sub>1</sub>, in this case we'd want to decrease (screen_width-x<sub>1</sub>), which is the same as *increasing* x<sub>1</sub>.  The same logic holds for replacing `y` with `(screen_height-y)`.

Comment: Now I understand why mathematics matters in programming!